# Criar um banco de dados em android

Tags: php, android, mysql

Ola pessoal estou aprendendo php e mysql e me surgiu a ideia de  hospedar um site de perguntas no meu celular e compartilhar wifi com meu amigos assim eles podem acessar meu site e responder ao meu quiz sem precisar de internet, só que não consigo imaginar uma forma de armazenar as respostas que eles iram me mandar e comparar com a dos outros, alguém pode me ajudar?

obs: para que meus amigos consigam acessar o meu site que está no meu celular usei o app "server for php" no meu samsung S5 e passo meu ip junto com a porta para que eles possam se  conectar pelo navegador.

se alguém tiver alguma sugestão de como posso compartilhar um site com meu amigos que possuem sistema diferentes(ios-android-win.phone) sem usar a internet e usando meu celular agradeceria.

Comment: O sistema Android encapsula as aplicações (que rodam em Java), desta forma, você precisaria fazer um aplicativo que crie um banco de dados e fizesse a comunicação com outros dispositivos. Não sei se esse APP "Server for PHP" te permite criar e gerenciar bancos, mas de qualquer forma, alguma aplicação é necessária.

Answer (score 0):

Pela última vez vou editar essa pergunta eu juro.

Você usa um servidor sem banco de dados, você precisa de outro aplicativo pra hospedar o seu site pros seus amigos e um servidor casado com banco de dados.

Eu pesquisei na PlayStore e achei alguns aplicativos bem interessantes onde você pode hospedar o banco de dados e o seu site:

*Ulti Server: PHP, MySQL, PMA
*KSWEB: server + PHP + MySQL

De uma olhada e veja se algum desses aplicativos satisfaz a sua necessidade.

Comment: Embora este link possa responder à pergunta, é melhor incluir as partes essenciais da resposta aqui e fornecer o link para referência.  As respostas apenas por link podem ser invalidadas se a página com o link for alterada. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/69236)

Comment: Retirei o link e botei uma sugestão.